# Can not run SQL update statement in vb.net,

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

I am currently working in Visual Studio 2013 Express with a SQL Server backend. I am trying to do a VERY SIMPLE update statement, but for some reason this thing will NOT run. It is beginning to frustate me on how this simple query will not run.

This form is supposed to move a part number from one machine to another. I have 3 comboboxes, combobox1 is FromMachine, combobox2 is the to machine, and combobox 3 is the part number.

My SQL Server table has a column for part number and cutting machine. All of this runs on a button click event. Please note that part number is a datetime and the machines are ints. Here is my code.

```
'Safety check
If Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please select a machine to move the Part from.")
        Exit Sub
End If

If Combobox2.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please select a machine to move the part to.")
        Exit Sub
End If

If Combobox3.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please select a part number to change from one cutting machine to another.")
        Exit Sub
End If

    Dim FromMachine As Integer = Combobox1.SelectedValue
    Dim ToMachine As Integer = Combobox2.SelectedValue
    Dim Part As DateTime = Combobox3.SelectedValue

    Try

        'sql command for the change
        'make sure that part isnt already on that machine
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT PartNumber FROM Table1 Where PartNumber = @PartNumber AND Machine = @ToMachine", conn1)
                comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartNumber", Part)
                comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToMachine", ToMachine)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sql.Fill(dt)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                'check for data entries
                If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Part Number " & Combobox3.SelectedText & " is already assigned to " & Combobox2.SelectedText & ". This Part could not be changed.")
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    'Make the change
                    Using conn2 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                        conn2.Open()
                        Using comm2 As New SqlCommand("UPDATE table1 SET Machine = @ToMachine Where Machine = @FromMachine " _
                                                       & "AND PartNumber = @PartNumber", conn1)
                            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToMachine", ToMachine)
                            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromMachine", FromMachine)
                            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", PartNumber)
                            comm1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            MsgBox("PartNumber " & Combobox3.SelectedText & " has been changed from cutting machine " & Combobox1.SelectedText & " To cutting machine " & Combobox2.SelectedText & ".")
                        End Using
                        conn2.Close()
                    End Using
                End If
            End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

In short, combobox 1 is the machine that the part number is being moved from, and combobox2 is the machine that the aprt is being moved too. The first sql statement checks to see if that part is already on that machine, because the same part will never be cut on the same machine twice. Then if that datagridview returns that nothing is already there, the second sql statement will run the update statement.

Also, all the comboboxes are loaded from a SQL query and they all have the correct values when I add watch them or plug the SQL statements into my visual management program.

----------UPDATE-------------

The code does run and I have stepped through it, however, once the code is done there are no changes made to SQL Server. I have put the SQL update statement into the Management Studio and plugged in the values, I got off the watches in my vb.net program and it will not change the machine. It is acting like it is doing the code but just not applying it to SQL Server.

------------Update-------------
error was using comm1 paramaters for comm2 and executing comm1 under comm2.

Comment: Instead of `AddWithValue` which infers the (possibly incorrect) type from the parameter-value use `Add(sqlParameterWithType).Value=value`.

Comment: What doesn't run?  Do you get an error?  Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: @Tim I have stepped through the code and I do not receive an error message. Once the code runs and I double check it on the server, it just doesn't make the change. I have added a watch to all my variables and they are all correct upon the sql statement running.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am not sure of that sql parameter type, Can you give me an example with a line from my code so I can try and plug it in.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, you can also use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx).  But note that you are using `Part` in the select-query and `PartNumber` in the update. In the `MessageBox.Show` you are even using a thrd option `Combobox3.SelectedText`. Which is correct?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will look at the overload, if you see a type-o in my queries please disregard. I have changed my table names and column names for privacy concerns. They have all been put into the sql server management studio to be tested.

Comment: HAve you checked for triggers?

Comment: What is your **connection string** to the database? Does it contain a `AttachDbFileName=.....` element ? This is **notoriously hairy** when doing local development in Visual Studio ....

Comment: You also don't need to open and close conn1, your data adpater does that for you.

Comment: If memory serves me... If you create a dataadapter with SQL that includes a primary key the Update code is created for you. You can then update the fields in the datatable rows and then call update on the adapter. I think the ADO.net call is CommandBuilders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the parameters to `comm1` instead of `comm2` and executing the wrong command too (thanks @clweeks for comment).

Comment: And executing comm1 as well.

Comment: that's it. That's embarrassing.